# How to display date in datetimepicker where days is base in numbers of label.text control?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, datetimepicker

I have example, if datetimepicker1 value is 19/06/2020 then I want datetimepicker2 value is 29/06/2020 because of label shows text is "10" and 10 is the date range. Correct me if I'm wrong, I want to display datetimepicker1 19/06/2020 then datetimepicker2 is 29/06/2020 since label shows 10. How?

Comment: What kind of app?  WinForms, WPF, WebForms, etc....?

Answer (score 0):

You've provided too little information to go on, but since you did tag your question with `C#`, then date manipulation should be fairly straightforward.

```
int days = Int32.Parse(someLabel.Text); //no validation; if the label contains a non-number this will throw an exception
DateTime date2 = date1.AddDays(days);  //assuming date1 is DateTime
```

Comment: what should I change in date2 and date1

Comment: @SHIRYU Without knowing your code there's no way I can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int daysToAdd;
    if (int.TryParse(label1.Text, out daysToAdd))
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);
    }
}
```